# swift xcode Mac カメロラールの写真は何処にあるか教えて戴けませんか

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

swiftで写真をカメロラールにクロップして保存するPGを作っているのですが、作った画像のサイズを知りたいのですが写真の場所がわかりません。何処にあるか教えて戴けませんか 
ネット環境でなくても画像が読み込めて保存もできるのでPC内だと思うのですが。
写真ホルダーでもないようです。

Comment: PGという略語は「プログラム」より「プログラマー(書く人)」を指して使われる事がほとんどです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

写真アプリ(Photots.app）の事をおたずねでしたら、
写真アプリを立ち上げて、環境設定→一般の一番上にライブラリーの場所というのがあります。

しかし、中のファイルはApple独自のデーターベース構造になっているので、
AppleのPhotos frameworkを使ってアクセスするのが良いかと思います。

Photos frameworkのドキュメントは[ここ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos)にあります。

SwiftからPhotos frameworkを呼び出す[サンプル](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/Shared_AssetViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-Shared_AssetViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_7)がAppleから提供されているので
これが参考になると思います。

Comment: Windowsフォルダーのようになっていて簡単に見れるのかと思いましたが、結構面倒そうですね。試して見ます。有難うございました。